# A boat is to be manned by 8 men,of whom 2 can only row on bow side & 1 can only row on stroke side;in how many ways can the crew be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I tried it by selecting 2 men out of 8 for bow side,and then arrange them in 2! ways.This can be done in$ \binom{8}{2}$*2! ways,and the stroke side can be crewed in 6 ways.So the required no. of ways are $\binom{8}{2}$*2!*6=336.
But,my answer is not matching.It's correct answer is 5760.

Please help me in pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See we don't want to select people we want to arrange people. Hence total ways are $^4P_2\times$$^4P_1\times$$^5P_5=5760$ assuming boat has 4 rowing on each side.

Answer (score 2):

You can select which two of the five who can row either side should row Bow in ${5\choose2}=10$ ways. That determines which four row Bow an which four row Stroke. Now you have $4!$ ways of arranging the Bow side and $4!$ ways of arranging the Stroke side. So total $10\cdot4!\cdot4!=5760$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, select seats for the three primadonnas first, which can be done in $4\cdot3\cdot 4$ ways. Afterwards the 5 remaining rowers can be seated in $5!$ ways, for a result of
$$ 4\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5!=5760 $$

Answer (score 1):

2 men sitting on a bow side can sit in 4!/2! ways, 1 man sitting on stroke side can site in 4 ways,remaining 5 can sit anywhere in 5! ways so 
 4!/2!*4*5!= 5760

Answer (score -1):

My answer is best as it is using basic principle
Consider 4 each on both sides
Then for 1st side we require 2 people so no. Of ways is 4(for 1st person)*3(for other one)
Then for 2nd side we require 1 person so he has 4 choice
Then for remaining 5 places we have 5*4*3*2*1 this (arrangement is of remaining people)