# A boat is to be manned by 8 crew members of whom 2 can only row on bow side and 3 can only row on stroke side, total number of arrangements possible?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations

I just want to verify my answer to this problem.
My answer :- Since 5 members are restricted to a single side, only 3 members remain with the ability to row on both sides. Now I already have 2 members on bow side, I need 2 more so I can select 2 out of 3 dual ability members in 3C2 ways. On stroke side I have 3 members and I need only 1 more members so I can select 1 members out of remaining 1 dual ability member in 1C1 way. Now I have to arrange members on row and stroke sides that will be 4! x 4!
Final answer :- 3C2 * 1C1 * 4! * 4!

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me. I guess the assumption that the boat has to have four people on each side is given or assumed by the context (it makes sense, but it's not mentioned).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A boat is to be manned by 8 men,of whom 2 can only row on bow side & 1 can only row on stroke side;in how many ways can the crew be arranged?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824256/a-boat-is-to-be-manned-by-8-men-of-whom-2-can-only-row-on-bow-side-1-can-only)